# How to free reallocated and callocated memory?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

How to free the memory which has been once callocated in the beggining, then reallocated and callocated right after? This ptr was my attempt but valgrind says that there has been 6 allocs and 6 frees, yet there are 90 bytes in 3 blocks definitely lost.

```
char *textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength + 1, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
char *currentLine = (char *) calloc(currentLength + 1, sizeof(char) * currentLineLength);
...
while ((textInFile[index] = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (index > currentLength - 3) {
        currentLength += 10;
        ptr = textInFile;
        textInFile = (char *) realloc(textInFile, currentLength);
        textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
        free(ptr);
    }
    ...
    if (textInFile[index] == '\n') {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = previousIndex; i < index; i++) {
            if (k > currentLineLength - 3) {
                currentLineLength += 10;
                ptr = currentLine;  
                currentLine = (char *) realloc(currentLine, currentLineLength);
                currentLine = (char *) calloc(currentLineLength, sizeof(char) * currentLineLength);
                free(ptr);
            }
    ...
    index++;
}
...
free(textInFile);
free(currentLine);
```

==4426== HEAP SUMMARY:

==4426==     in use at exit: 90 bytes in 3 blocks

==4426==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 14,668 bytes allocated

==4426==

==4426== LEAK SUMMARY:

==4426==    definitely lost: 90 bytes in 3 blocks

==4426==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==4426==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==4426==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==4426==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `free()` on every non-NULL pointer that was returned by `calloc()`.  If you call `realloc()`, then you shouldn't call `free()` on the pointer that you passed in as an argument to `realloc()`, but you should call `free()` on the pointer that `realloc()` returned.  (Note:  using `realloc()` correctly is tricky, especially if you want to handle errors correctly -- I recommend avoiding it unless it's strictly necessary)

One problem in particular with your code is this:

```
textInFile = (char *) realloc(textInFile, currentLength);
textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
```

In the second line you overwrite `textInFile`'s pointer with the pointer returned by `calloc()`, thus losing any access to the old value that was returned by `realloc()`, so you have no way to free that buffer; hence you have a memory leak.

Comment: But isn't ptr doing the job?

Comment: Not after you overwrite it with the new value returned from `calloc()`; as soon as you do that, nothing is pointing to the buffer that was returned by `realloc()` anymore.  Pointers don't keep a list of all the memory addresses they were previously assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

I think.. that you are misunderstanding `realloc`.

`realloc` is not `free`.

It returns alloacted memory..

your code

```
        textInFile = (char *) realloc(textInFile, currentLength);
        textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
        free(ptr);
```

`textInFile` was alloacted twice.. 1st pointer is leaked..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the end of the code. I actually free them. It's been edited.

Comment: @tomashauser hmm.. Please read my answer carefully... You allocated TWICE.. and free ONCE..

Answer (score 0):

**The answer:**

`ptr` should have pointed to `realloc` which should have been freed. In the question, the original adress of textInFile was lost since it was overwritten.

```
ptr = (char *) realloc(currentLine, currentLineLength);
currentLine = (char *) calloc(currentLineLength, sizeof(char) * currentLineLength);
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make any sense:

```
textInFile = (char *) realloc(textInFile, currentLength);
textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
```

Why are you calling `calloc` after the `realloc`?  What do you think that code is doing?  If you're trying to zero out the extended memory, that won't work.

If you want to extend (`realloc`) a buffer, here's the general procedure for doing so.  Assuming you allocated the buffer as

```
T *buffer = calloc( number_of_items, sizeof *buffer ); // sizeof *buffer == sizeof (T)
```

for some type `T`, you'd extend the buffer as follows:

```
T *tmp = realloc( buffer, (number_of_items + number_of_new_items) * sizeof *buffer );
if ( tmp )
{
  buffer = tmp;
  number_of_items += number_of_new_items;
}
else
{
  // reallocation was not successful, handle as appropriate
}
```

As a rule, you do not want to assign the result of `realloc` to the original pointer.  If `realloc` fails, it will return `NULL` while leaving the current buffer in place, and you will overwrite your original pointer value (leading to a memory leak).  You also don't want to update your size until you know the operation was successful.  It's best to assign the result to a temporary pointer, then after you're sure it was successful, assign the temporary to your original pointer.

You don't need to call `calloc` after calling `realloc`.  You only need to call `calloc` once, when you initially allocate the buffer.  You can also use `realloc` for the initial allocation, you just pass `NULL` as the first parameter:

```
T *buffer = realloc( NULL, number_of_items * sizeof *buffer );
```

**Edit**

Applying this to your code:

```
while ((textInFile[index] = getc(f)) != EOF) {
  if (index > currentLength - 3) {
    ptr = realloc(textInFile, currentLength + 10);
    if ( ptr )
    {
      currentLength += 10;
      textInFile = ptr; 
    }
    else
    {
      // unable to extend textInFile
    }
    ...
        if (k > currentLineLength - 3) {
            ptr = realloc( currentLine, currentLineLength + 10 );
            if ( ptr )
            {
              currentLineLength += 10;
              currentLine = ptr;  
            }
            else
            {
              // unable to extend currentLine
            }
        }
```

When you're done, you'd free as

```
free( currentLine );
free( textInFile );
```

You don't need to free `ptr` at any point in this - you're only using it to store a temporary value.

Comment: I need to use it, otherwise I get invalid read of size 1 and invalid write of size one. There must be something in the string.

Comment: @tomashauser: Need to use what, the `calloc` call?

Comment: Yes, it's HW with extremely strict valgrind.